# Why does the map item content appear in poor resolution in print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing

[image]I started a print composer project and added my map onto the composer canvas and it was displayed with really poor resolution. My map consists of a georeferenced jpeg ( big 90Mb) and a slope layer overlay on top.
Why is it displayed with very poor resolution?
Is that what the print will look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map contents do not scale when you zoom in or out. You have to refresh the map layout by pressing f5 when you have the map selected. This will "update" the map to view the correst resolution for your current zoom. 
When you print the map it will of course display a sharp image.

Answer (score 0):

Come across this issue again with one of my students trying to map census data in polygons, using QGIS version 3.28. The main map view (prior to New Print Layout as it is now known) is crisp, but when you import into New Print Layout it is not. Even the "refresh" solution above does not work. However, when exporting the map as PDF and PNG the map contents are crisp again.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/258987)

Comment: Gives context that the issue is still occurring over 6 years after the initial question was asked, the accepted answer may not work in later versions of the software and also provides a useful workaround for the current situation.